# Webpack module federation error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to create the most basic *webpack module federation* proof of concept example.

Webpack config in the host app:

```
...
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "hostApp",
      remotes: {
        libApp: `libApp@http://localhost:3000/libApp`,
      },
    }),
  ],
...
```

Webpack config in the dependency app:

```
...
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "libApp",
      filename: "libApp.js",
      exposes: {
        "./moduleA": "./src/moduleA",
        "./moduleB": "./src/moduleB",
      }
    })
  ],
...
```

**[Here is the reproduction repo](https://github.com/danierlr/WebpackModuleFederationError)**

What is wrong with this configuration?

Also, is it possible to set up dependency app to export a single *js* file with all exposed modules included (as a single webpack module)?

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this creating a new file "bootstrap.js" in hostApp.

```
// src/bootstrap.js
console.log('host app test')

import moduleA from 'libApp/moduleA'
import moduleB from 'libApp/moduleB'

const el = document.getElementById('hostAppContainer')

el.innerHTML = 'changedContent: ' + moduleA + moduleB
```

and then change your index.js to

```
// src/index.js

import("./bootstrap");
```

This was caused by trying to do module federation in the initial entry point, which webpack doesn't like you doing.

Comment: You are my savior.
Can you explain why webpack don't permit to import a module inside the `index.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I see several things.

1. I think the `remotes` property goes in the dependent apps as a link back to the host application.
2. Similarly, I think you'll need a `filename` inside the host application's configuration for remote access.
3. It looks odd to me to have your dependent apps directly inside the `src` directory and not inside `src/app`.